# one ViewModel per each composable page inside HorizontalPager

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm converting my project from view system to compose. In one of app page's in old view system I have a fragment with one viewPager which just make some pages of same fragment with different data to show. While each fragment has it's own lifecycle I can have multiple isolated viewModel per each fragment. In Compose as far as I know viewModel life cycle is attached to navigation graph, therefor each time I try to access viewModel it just return same viewModel object that's created in first call. how can I achieve same view system behavior in compose?

this is simplified version of what my app is doing now

```
@Composable
fun MainScreen(mainViewModel: MainViewModel = hiltViewModel()) {
    val pages = mainViewModel.pages.collectAsState()
    val pagerState = rememberPagerState(pageCount = pages.size)
    HorizontalPager(state = pagerState) {
        ChildScreen()
    }
}

@Composable
fun ChildScreen(childViewModel:ChildViewModel = hiltViewModel()){
    
}
```

here `childViewModel` is always one object for all pages

Comment: With normal view models you can use `key` in this case, which will create different representation models for different keys. But Hilt does not currently support keys, and there doesn't seem to be a way to bypass injections. I suggest you [create a development request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=612128) on the compose issue tracker

Comment: maybe the solution here is departing from hilt and instantiating your viewmodels explicitly. but then you would have to deal with the livecycle of those analog viewmodels yourself. Or you could try to place the state you require for ChildScreen into a hashMap of protoViewModels that you could place inside MainViewModel. and then passing the values in that hashmap to each ChildScreen(childViewModel = mainViewModel.hashmap.get(pageId))

Comment: New hilt version supports key for viewmodel https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/hilt#1.1.0-alpha01

Answer (score 4):

As @Pavlov Svyatoslav commented, first of all you need a new version of navigation. For now, it is 1.1.0-alpha01

```
implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.1.0-alpha01")
```

Then you can add a key for hiltViewModel() function like this:

```
@Composable
fun ChildScreen(childViewModel:ChildViewModel = hiltViewModel(key = "what_key")){
    
}
```

The problem here is what key should we use? if we use a random key, maybe the system will always create a new ViewModel for the same ChildScreen. Right? So my solution is let MainScreen creates an instance of ChildViewModel then passes it to ChildScreen:

```
  @Composable
    fun MainScreen(mainViewModel: MainViewModel = hiltViewModel()) {
        val pages = mainViewModel.pages.collectAsState()
        val pagerState = rememberPagerState(pageCount = pages.size)
        HorizontalPager(state = pagerState) {index ->
val childViewModel  = hiltViewModel(key = index.toString) // or any key in here
            ChildScreen(childViewModel)
        }
    }
    
    @Composable
    fun ChildScreen(childViewModel:ChildViewModel){
        
    }
```

Comment: Works for me, thx. Also I changed ChildScreen to ChildScreen(page: Int, viewModel: ChildViewModel = hiltViewModel(key = page.toString())) so that ChildScreen is more isolated and like the view system setup.